# MySQL database items wont update. PHP wont enter if($_POST['edit_submit'])

Tags: php, html, mysql, database, phpmyadmin

I'm trying to update my tasks page with new values for the tasks. My form looks like this:

```
<?php if (isset($_GET['edit_task'])): ?>
    <form action="" method="POST" class="form-inline">
        <td class="task">
            <div class="form-group mr-sm-3 mb-2 inputfield">
                <input type="text" name="taskvalue" class="form-control col-12" value="<?php echo $row['task'] ?>">
            </div>
        </td>
        <td class="date">
            <div class="form-group mr-sm-3 mb-2 inputfield">
                <input type="date" name="datevalue" class="form-control col-12" value="<?php echo $row['duedate'] ?>">
            </div>                                    
        </td>
        <td class="edit" style="font-size: 0.8rem;">
            <button type="submit" name="edit_submit" class="btn btn-primary mb-2">Edit</button>
            <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?=$row['id']?>">
        </td>
    </form>
<?php else: ?>
    <td class="task">
        <?php echo $row['task'] ?>
    </td>
    <td class="date">
        <?php echo $row['duedate'] ?>
    </td>
    <td class="delete edit move" style="font-size: 0.8rem;">
        <a href="index.php?move_task=<?php echo $row ['id']; ?>"><i class="fas fa-check-square fa-2x"></i></a>
        <a href="index.php?edit_task=<?php echo $row ['id']; ?>"><i class="fas fa-pen-square fa-2x"></i></a>
        <a href="index.php?del_task=<?php echo $row ['id']; ?>"><i class="fas fa-minus-square fa-2x"></i></a>
    </td>
<?php endif ?>
```

And my PHP code to update the values looks like this:

```
//edit items to database
if (isset($_GET['edit_task'])) {
    if (isset($_POST['edit_submit'])) {
        $id = $_POST['id'];
        $task = $_POST['taskvalue'];
        $rawdate = htmlentities($_POST['datevalue']);
        $insertdate = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($rawdate));

        if (empty($task)) {
            $message['type'] = "error";
            $message['text'] = "You must fill in a task first.";
        } else {
            mysqli_query($db, "UPDATE tasks (task, duedate) SET (task = '$task', duedate = $insertdate) WHERE id = $id");

            header('location: index.php');
        }
        $debuglog2 = "edit task working 2";
    }
    $debuglog1 = "edit task working 1";
}
```

You see the `$debuglog1 = "edit task working 1";`? It shows this one in my page when I press [the update icon](https://i.gyazo.com/c64870501a4fa8c83df3e640a513c8a6.png). So that first `if (isset($_GET['edit_task']))` is working. The second debuglog, `$debuglog2`, wont show on my website after I press [the edit button](https://i.gyazo.com/b4ac00169b9aabb20b73d65d6f8ea892.png), so I think that it wont enter `if (isset($_POST['edit_submit']))`. The 2 debuglogs are both echo'd outside my table in my HTML. Images of the icon and button are accessible by pressing the links above. [HERE](https://i.gyazo.com/a3993579a36fcdb0232609212f977916.mp4) is a video that summarizes my problem.

The application is also capable of adding tasks to the database. This part works fine. I use the same form to update my tasks, except the name attribute is different, and I use the same PHP script to update the tasks, except this one has an UPDATE Query and checks if the edit icon is pressed in the beginning.

I have tried switching `if`s, I have put and `input hidden id` element in my form, my button is named `edit_submit` and my form is a `POST`. I have no idea why it wont enter this second if statement. My SQL query is correct I think, even tho it wont even show the debuglog in the same hierarchy. I have tried changing between `$_GET` and `$_POST` and yet nothing changes. This is one of the most simple things you can do in SQL but yet I can't get it to work. YouTube and other forum posts already tell me what I have typed down so I have no idea what is wrong. Anyone that can help? Thanks in advance.

Comment: `$_GET['edit_task']` won't be set in the POST request when submitting the form.

Comment: @arkascha what do you mean?

Comment: In your code that implements the actual update attempt you test for variables of _both_ superglobal arrays: `$_GET` _and_ `$_POST`. Your form defines a POST request without specifying a URL, so I would assume that `$_GET` does not contain any value. Which would result in you never entering your update logic.

Comment: Apart from that: your code is vulnerable to sql injection attacks. You definitely want to learn about the benefits of using the combination of "prepared statements" and "parameter binding" to prevent such vulnerability.

Comment: @arkascha okey, I changed `action=""` to `action="index.php"` and it still wont do anything.

Comment: You did not really read what I wrote.

Comment: If you POST the form to `index.php`, why do you expect `$_GET['edit_task']` to be set?

Comment: I am afraid I do not fully understand what you mean then. Excuse me.

Comment: Then take some time to think about what I wrote. Or check yourself what `$_GET` actually contains in your updating logic...

Comment: I have commented out `if (isset($_GET['edit_task']))`, since my button name is `edit_submit` and it is unique, so I should not have to do the extra check. After removing the first if, it still wont work

Comment: And "it won't work" means what? What happens? Is your update logic executed _at all_? What does your http servers error log file reveal what the actual issue is? Did you at least _try_ to debug this?

Comment: Nothing happens, nothing gets updated at all, `$_GET['edit_task']` only checks if a button is pressed, the button to reveal my update form, and yes, ofcourse I have tried to debug this, otherwise I would not be posting this to stackoverflow. Also, I have never heard or learned about anything about this logfile.

Comment: You still fail to understand when some value is set in `$_GET` and when not. I suggest you actually do what I suggest: check what `$_GET` actually contains instead of blindly assuming things. And next you really should start reading the documentation of the tools you use. You _can not_ implement in a http server based environment without monitoring the http servers error log file. That would be like flying inside a narrow case with your eyes blind folded. Sure, one can do that, but it is a pretty stupid thing to do...

Comment: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/php_get_post.htm

Answer (score -1):

When a form gets posted, the $_GET variable will have nothing in it. Only the $_POST will contain data. So your check of $_GET is failing, precisely because you have posted a form.

The log file (in case of apache web-server) is (in case of a *nix environment) usually located in a file called /var/log/apache2/error.log and /var/log/apache2/access.log...

You can usually open a terminal and type the following:

sudo tail -f /var/log/apache2/error.log ... this would constantly update your terminal with the newest logs being accumulated by apache2... which would show your PHP errors as well and that would make your life a lot easier.

Comment: "When a form gets posted, the $_GET variable will have nothing in it." — That's probably not true. The `$_GET` superglobal will contain anything in the query string. Since the `action` is set to `""`, the query string when the form is POSTed will contain anything that was in the query string when the page containing the form was loaded.

Comment: Oh okay, oops! :) Thanks for the information @Quentin